# What's the word for "to have a quality, idea or emotion faintly"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that "be imbued with" is used to mean "to have a a quality, idea or emotion very strongly".
But what's the word for "to have a quality, idea or emotion faintly and indistinctly"?

Answer (score 1):

@Jason Bassford has made good suggestions, IMO (hint, and trace).

You could also use phraseology like "to have a **[soupcon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soup%C3%A7on)** of"

> **[soup·çon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soup%C3%A7on)** *[so͞opˈsoN] NOUN - a very small quantity of something
>
> *"The board's final report had a soupcon of concern over the adverse combination of new business competitors and increased manufacturing costs and the potential this might have on projected earnings. Overall though, the health of the company is very stable and business is proceeding as per usual."*

You could also try more abstract approaches like:

- "X *has **[elements](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/element)** of* Y," or even
- "A *has **[touches](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touch)** of* B"

Answer (score 1):

I like ***whiff***, because you get that instant visual of somebody with their nostrils flaring.

Some dictionaries don't have it, but MW has one definition as "...slight trace or indication...", so, you could use it in that sense.

Comment: whiffy whiff whifferroo. whi-fi

Comment: @Carly ...Yes, it is a good word.

Comment: What's you whi-fhy password? =)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word [**hint**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hint):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **3** : a slight indication of the existence, approach, or nature of something : CLUE
>   // gave only a *hint* of what was to come
>   **4** : a very small amount : SUGGESTION
>   // with just a *hint* of spice

Additional example sentences (my own):

> He has a *hint* of the Devil in him.
>   I have a *hint* of an idea.
>   She has a *hint* of the long-distance runner about her.
>   Do I detect a *hint* of hostility?

In some of those sentences, [*trace*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trace) could also be used. However, it wouldn't work as well in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was "inkling".  As in he had an inkling something was awry.

Inkling: a slight knowledge or suspicion; a hint.